# Jupyter in VSCode Failing to Start Kernel

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been using Jupyter within VSCode with no problems for a couple weeks, but since this morning it has been unable to start a kernel to run my code.

Typically, I can just open any .ipynb file in VSCode and immediately run it with no problems. That's giving me the message:

```
Failed to start the Kernel. 
Jupyter server crashed. Unable to connect. 
Error code from Jupyter: 1
usage: jupyter.py [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
                  [--paths] [--json] [--debug]
                  [subcommand]

Jupyter: Interactive Computing

positional arguments:
  subcommand     the subcommand to launch

options: 
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --version      show the versions of core jupyter packages and exit
  --config-dir   show Jupyter config dir
  --data-dir     show Jupyter data dir
  --runtime-dir  show Jupyter runtime dir
  --paths        show all Jupyter paths. Add --json for machine-readable
             format.
  --json         output paths as machine-readable json
  --debug        output debug information about paths

Available subcommands: dejavu lab labextension labhub nbconvert

Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

I can, however, open a local host in a browser using:

```
python3 -m notebook
```

in my terminal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Seems there was an issue in a previous release of the Jupyter extension for VScode (see : [1])

I resolved as suggested in [1] :

- uninstall jupyter from your global environment
- set up a virtual environment
- install jupyter in the new virtual env
- select the virtual env as kernel used in VScode
- run some cells (should work)

In case you want to use jupyter in your global environment :

- remove the virtual environment
- reinstall jupyter in your global env
- select the correct global env interpreter in VScode

[1] https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/12714